# Revision to a IEEE paper

Tags: publications, ieee

I am submitting a revision to paper I submitted to a IEEE journal.

1. When I wrote out the letter addressing the revisions, I included some graphics in my comments as well. But when I look at the ScholarOne website, it seems like the letter to “Respond to Decision Letter” is a text only format. Does anybody know whether you can submit a word document/pdf to respond to the decision letter instead of submitting a text-only letter?
2. Do you typically have to submit a new Cover letter if you revised the paper/letter? Or should I just keep the cover letter the same as the cover letter that I used to submit the original paper?

Comment: Can you submit a supplementary file with those comments?  And I think the new cover letter can simply say you hope you have addressed the comments, and maybe reference the attachment.

Comment: was it already published or it is still under review? not clear from the question

Comment: @Tommy, the paper is still under review..I am resubmitting the paper after addressing comments from reviewers..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the final step of the submission to manuscriptcentral, in the same page where you upload your revised manuscript, you will also upload the letter as supplementary material.  This means that your letter will be combined with your manuscript as a pdf and your reviewers will only have to download one document.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out.. Didnt realize I could add the comments as a supplementary Files..

Answer (score 1):

1. In the textbox, just say 'See attachment'.  On the page where you upload your revised paper, there is usually an option to upload other files.  Use the option to upload your responses to the reviewers. Just double check that the compiled pdf include your responses as well as the revised paper.
2. Same cover letter, but you may want to add '..revised paper'.